# mobicents jain slee hello world serivce for beginner

Tags: mobicents

I am trying to build a simple jain slee project by following the steps given here
https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HelloSLEEWorldServiceJAINSLEETutorial
 but when i try to create a service i get an error message [error message scr shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ2a4.png) 
can anyone help me

Comment: Please show us the part of code causing the error, and not only a link ...

Comment: I cannot find where the error is and what the error is i am simply following the baisc steps

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but I will answer nevertheless for future visitors' sake.

The issue is with the Eclipslee service creation plugin. Can you install one from [here](http://mobicents.googlecode.com/svn/downloads/eclipse-update-site/plugins/) and try to create the service again.

If not find the plugin jar file named;

org.mobicents.eclipslee.servicecreation_2.0.0.v20130704-2333.jar

This is the one I use. But I think the 2.0.0.FINAL should do the job. I can't upload the exact file because I don't remember where I got it from. Probably a forum somewhere or an issue tracker thread. But can't quote the source properly. :(

P.S.(in case you didn't know) Installation == Copying the jar file to the plugins directory in Eclipse.

edit:
[This](https://www.mail-archive.com/mobicents-all-issues-changes@googlegroups.com/msg18320.html) is another workaround. v2.0.0 apparently does not work too.